# PHP reorder an array at random

Tags: php, arrays

I need to reorder an array at random but I am not sure what the best/cleanest/fastest way is to do this.

So what I am trying to achieve is the following. Let's say I have an array that looks like this:

```
$array = array(4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8, 10, 10, 20, 40, 60);
```

My goal is to get something like this but at random:

```
$array = array(6, 4, 4, 10, 4, 6, 4, 6, 60, 6, 8, 6, 10, 40, 8, 20);
```

Here's what I've been trying but it doesn't seem to be working as intended:

```
$array = array(4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8, 10, 10, 20, 40, 60);
$newArray = array();

$randomNumber = rand(0 , 14);

for ($x = 0; $x <= 15; $x++) {
    $newArray[$x] = $array[$randomNumber];
}
```

Many thanks in advance to anyone who can help me out :)

Comment: [`shuffle( $array )`](http://php.net/shuffle).

Comment: @Darren Is it that simple? I am trying to build something in PHP that I have built in C# and it was a lot harder in C# lol :)

Comment: Haha it is indeed, you simply run that function and it'll shuffle the current array :)

Comment: @Darren okay cool thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 3):

Use shuffle() function.
shuffle($array);

http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php

Answer (score 3):

```
$array = array(4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8, 10, 10, 20, 40, 60);
```

Check the output of previous array

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";
```

Shuffling previous array & check output again.

```
shuffle($array);
print_r($array);
```

Now run a foreach loop like

```
foreach($array as $item){
  echo $item;
}
```

**Note:** You don't need to store shuffle data to new array.